# Curve Bevel going outwards not inwards

Tags: modeling

How come my bevel is going outwards and not inwards? I'm trying to create molding but can't get it to go in the right direction

[image]
[image]

Comment: rotate the bevel object 180° in edit mode

Comment: This has been spam edited and is awaiting moderator intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two way to do this :

- Rotate the bevel object in edit mode 180°
- Select the curve ( not the bevel object ) , enter Edit mode and select all points with <kbd>A</kbd> (or twice) than adjust the tilt angle from the transform panel :

[image]

Comment: @Peter did you rotate in edit mode